# How to automatically include autoloader to PHP script?

Tags: php

I wan't to run php classes scripts from my IDE with PHP CLI.
When I launch files in which there are other classess specified, PHP shows error - because it can't find this classes. What should I add to command-line to automatically include my autoloader into the launching script?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://php.net/spl-autoload-register

Comment: Add the path to the autoloader script to  `auto_prepend_file` in the CLI php.ini.

Comment: -d auto_prepend_file="path_to_autoloader" - great, it works!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I nedded to just add an Interpreter option:

> -d auto_prepend_file="path to autoloader"